# Printing Magic Square

Tags: java, printing, magic-square

So I'm trying to print a magic Square. The program is complete but when it prints the magic square it comes out reversed. The output for a 3X3 should look like this:

```
8    1    6 
3    5    7 
4    9    2
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
4    9    2
3    5    7
8    1    6
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help would be great. Here's my code for making the magic square and also printing it:

```
  //magic square
  public static int[][] magicSq(int[][]table,int size){
    int [][]magic=new int[size][size];
    int row=size-1;
    int col=size/2;
    magic[row][col]=1;

    for(int i=2;i<=size*size;i++){
      if(magic[(row+1)%size][(col+1)%size]==0){
        row=(row+1)%size;
        col=(col+1)%size;
      }
      else{
        row=(row-1+size)%size;
      }
      magic[row][col]=i;
    }
    return magic;
  }

  //print magic sqaure
  public static void printSq(int[][]magic,int size){
    int constant=0;
    for(int r=0;r<size;r++){
      for(int c=0;c<size;c++)
        System.out.printf("%5d",magic[r][c]);
      System.out.println();
      constant=constant+magic[r][0];
    }
    System.out.println("The magic square contant is "+constant);
  }
```

Comment: try changing `magic[row][col]=i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only problem is that it's printing the rows in the opposite order from what you'd like you can just change the order in which you print the rows:

```
for(int r=size-1;r>=0;r--)
```

Also, I'm a little confused by your code.  The method magicSq is accepting an int[][]table as a parameter but then never does anything at all with it.  Is the code supposed to do something with that table?

Comment: Thanks that helped, been looking at it too long to see the simple mistake. And no the int[][]table as a parameter shouldn't have been there at all, I took it out and my program runs just fine.